# Save and load data from sqlite to calendar view from Applandeo library

Tags: android, android-sqlite, calendarview

I'm using Calendarview from applandeo library. I have it in a way such that I select several days in the calendar view and I want to store it in a SQLite database and load it later. This is the way I tried to pick several days from the calendar view:

```
private List<Calendar> getSelectedDays() {
    List<Calendar> calendars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Calendar calendar = DateUtils.getCalendar();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
        calendars.add(calendar);
    }
    return calendars;
}
```

This way it sets 10 days after the current day.

And this is the way I tried to show events on the calendar view:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
    events.add(new EventDay(calendar1, R.drawable.sample_icon_2));
```

How can i store the dates selected into the sqlite database and then load it?

From this I can get the day, month and year selected and store it into the database:
    for (Calendar calendar : calendarView.getSelectedDates()) {
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toString());

```
        dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        monthOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        dbManager.insertWORKING(dayOfMonth,monthOfYear,year);

        System.out.println("DATES: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+year);
    }
```

But then I don't know how to load it.

Answer (score 0):

You would add a method to the dbManager class to [**query**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) the database.

Such a method would be along the lines of

```
public Cursor retrieveAllWorkings() {
    SQliteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(your_tableName,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

- Obviously **your_tableName** should be replaced with a the actual table name.
- The above will extract ALL rows from the table into a [**Cursor**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
- as the 2nd parameter is null all of the table's columns are extracted into the **Cursor**.

You then loop (**move** using ) through the Cursor using the appropriate **get????** methods to retrieve the data from the respective columns. For flexibility and for less chance of errors it is a good idea to not hard-code column offsets but to instead utilise the Cursor **getColumnIndex** method to retrieve a column's offset from the column name.

**Note** you should always [**close**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close()) a Cursor when done with it.

As an example :-

```
while(the_cursor.moveToNext) {
    String my_extracted_data = the_cursor.getString(the_cursor.getColumnIndex(the_column_name));
    //........ do something with my_extracted_data as it will be overwritten by the next iteration (row in the Cursor)
}
```